# Fish shell: test: Missing argument at index 2

Tags: fish

I have the following function:

```
function is_file
  set file $argv[1]

  if test ‐f $file
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  end
end
```

However when calling it:

```
is_file ~/.vimrc
```

I get:

```
test: Missing argument at index 2
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I was not able to get an error as you described the function: `is_file ~/.viminf & echo $status` prints `1`. `is_file ~/.viminfo & echo $status` prints `0`. Are you sure that your `if` statement is typed exactly as it is above? Even removing the `set file $argv[1]` line and replacing the `if` statement with `if test -f $argv[1]`, it still worked as expected.

Comment: You have to look closely, but `‐` is not `-`. :)

Comment: BTW, `set file $argv[1]` is declaring a global variable needlessly, use `set -l file $argv[1]` instead. Also, you don't need to `return 0` or `return 1` because `is_file` will return the same as `test`. In fact, `[ -f $argv[1] ]` is good enough.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is the hyphen in the line

```
    if test ‐f $file
```

It is encoded as a Unicode hyphen U+2010, but it should be the ASCII hyphen-minus (0x2D) which is Unicode character U+002D.  If I delete the hyphen and retype it myself, it works fine for me.

By the way, this function could be written more concisely:

```
function is_file
    test -f $argv[1]
end
```