# fish: if error: `[: Missing argument at index 2`

Tags: if-statement, fish

I am a first-time Fish user and curently I try to convert my Bash prompt (`PS1`) to `fish_prompt`, which I save to `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish`.

This is a similar problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483919/fish-shell-test-missing-argument-at-index-2), however, the solution does not work for me.

I tried to remove the `[]`, use `test`, however, I have no idea how to compare strings in Fish

```
if [ $prompt_hostname == 'remote-host' ]
    set userHost remote
else
    set userHost local
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote the variable, and replace `==` with `=` (as the former is a bashism).

The issue is that, just like in bash, an empty variable is removed before it reaches the command, so `[` (which is just another name for `test`) gets its arguments like this:

```
[ == 'remote-host' ]
```

which isn't a valid expression.

So, this needs to be

```
if [ "$prompt_hostname" = 'remote-host' ]
```

or

```
if test "$prompt_hostname" = remote-host
```

(note that quoting the literal string is unnecessary but harmless in both - it changes nothing, because that string does not have any parts that would be expanded - no `$`, no `*`, no `()`, ....)